# JavaScript Regex: How to split html string into array of html elements and text nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

For example, this html string:

```html
Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor <span class="abc">sit</span> amet,<br/>consectetur <input value="ok"/> adipiscing elit.
```

into this array:

```js
[ 
  'Lorem ',
  '<b>ipsum</b>',
  ' dolor ', 
  '<span class="abc">sit</span>', 
  ' amet,', 
  '<br/>', 
  'consectetur ', 
  '<input value="ok"/>', 
  'adipiscing elit.' 
]
```

Here is the example of html elements match:

```js
const pattern = /<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/\1>|<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*).*?\/>/gi;
let html = 'Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor <span class="abc">sit</span> amet,<br/>consectetur <input value="ok"/> adipiscing elit.'
let nodes = html.match(pattern);

console.log(nodes)
```

How to add the text nodes as well?

Comment: Is `<b>ipsum<b/>` a typo? Did you mean `<b>ipsum</b>`?

Comment: Yes, `<b>ipsum<b/>` is a typo. Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the HTML is formatted properly, consider using DOMParser instead, to select all children, then take each child's `.outerHTML` (for element nodes) or `.textContent` (for text nodes):

```js
const str = `Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor <span class="abc">sit</span> amet,<br/>consectetur <input value="ok"/> adipiscing elit.`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const arr = [...doc.body.childNodes]
  .map(child => child.outerHTML || child.textContent);
console.log(arr);
```

You don't *have* to use DOMParser - you could also put the string into an ordinary element on the page, then take that element's children, but that'll allow for arbitrary code execution, which should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance! I'm looping through an array of mixed strings and applying the code above. Do you know if this will cause performance issues? Any suggestions if it does?

Comment: A snippet of code like this one is extremely unlikely to have any performance implications at all unless you're doing something odd like parsing 100 pages a second - in which case downloading would be the bottleneck instead. A decent rule of thumb is to not think much about performance unless you're in a tight loop, or *know* that something needs to be optimized.