# Using JavaScript, how do I transform an HTML string into an array of HTML tags and text content?

Tags: javascript, html, domparser

I have an HTML string such as:

```
<p>
    <strong><em>Lorem Ipsum </em></strong>is simply dummy text of the printing <em>and</em> typesetting industry.
</p>
```

I want to convert this into a JavaScript array that looks like:

```
['<p>', '<strong>', '<em>', 'Lorem Ipsum ', '</em>', '</strong>', 'is simply dummy text of the printing ', '<em>', 'and', '</em>', 'typesetting industry.', '</p>']
```

I.e. it takes the HTML string and breaks it down into an array of tags and HTML content.

I have tried to use `DomParser()` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61049576/javascript-regex-how-to-split-html-string-into-array-of-html-elements-and-text) question:

```
const str = `<p><strong><em>Lorem Ipsum </em></strong>is simply dummy text of the printing <em>and</em> typesetting industry.</p>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const arr = [...doc.body.childNodes]
  .map(child => child.outerHTML || child.textContent);
```

However, this simply returns:

```
['<p><strong><em>Lorem Ipsum </em></strong>is simply dummy text of the printing <em>and</em> typesetting industry.</p>']
```

I have also tried to search for various Regex based solutions, but haven't been able to find any that break down the string exactly as I require.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: [Don't use regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/966798)

Comment: Whats the point? If you create a div with `const frag = document.createElement('div'); frag.innerHTML = thatString;`, then you can get Elements from that `frag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a recursive function to iterate over a given node and return an array of the text representation of its children:

```js
const str = `<p><strong><em>Lorem Ipsum </em></strong>is simply dummy text of the printing <em>and</em> typesetting industry.</p>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const parseNode = node => {
  const output = [];
  for (const child of node.childNodes) {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      output.push(child.textContent);
    } else if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      output.push(`<${child.tagName}>`);
      output.push(...parseNode(child));
      output.push(`</${child.tagName}>`);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
console.log(parseNode(doc.body));
```

If you need to keep attributes too, you could take the `outerHTML` of the element and take the leading non-brackets:

```js
const str = `<p style="color:green"><strong><em>Lorem Ipsum </em></strong>is simply dummy text of the printing <em>and</em> typesetting industry.</p>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const parseNode = node => {
  const output = [];
  for (const child of node.childNodes) {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      output.push(child.textContent);
    } else if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      const attribs = child.outerHTML.match(/<\s*[^>\s]+([^>]*)/)[1];
      output.push(`<${child.tagName}${attribs}>`);
      output.push(...parseNode(child));
      output.push(`</${child.tagName}>`);
    }
  }
  return output;
};
console.log(parseNode(doc.body));
```

If you need self-closing tags not to be expanded, check if the `outerHTML` of an element contains `</`:

```js
const str = `<p style="color:green"><input readonly value="x"/><strong><em>Lorem Ipsum </em></strong>is simply dummy text of the printing <em>and</em> typesetting industry.</p>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const parseNode = node => {
  const output = [];
  for (const child of node.childNodes) {
    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      output.push(child.textContent);
    } else if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      const attribs = child.outerHTML.match(/<\s*[^>\s]+([^>]*)/)[1];
      output.push(`<${child.tagName}${attribs}>`);
      if (child.outerHTML.includes('</')) {
        // Not self closing:
        output.push(...parseNode(child));
        output.push(`</${child.tagName}>`);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
};
console.log(parseNode(doc.body));
```

Comment: Could you convert the magic numbers to constants?

Comment: @TedBrownlow for a quick reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType

Comment: does this take into account a self closing tag?

Comment: @MatinKajabadi If expanding them is a problem for you, I guess you can check if the `outerHTML` contains `</` or not

Comment: @CertainPerformance I believe Parser ignores the `/` in the tag and treats it as an opening tag then, even though there is no closing tag in the code, the parser constructs one in memory like:

`<b />`  => `<b>....</b>`

Comment: @MatinKajabadi My parser, or DOMParser? DOMParser will interpret the markup as accurately as it can. If the element must be a valid self-closing element, the browser will omit the end tags in the `outerHTML`.

Comment: I was wrong, HTML parser does that not XML parser.

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is exactly what I need, thanks!! You went above and beyond with your answer, which is highly appreciated, kudos :)