# How to split html code from a page into nodes

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I want to read the html from a site and then split it into nodes. I tried this code:

```
function load() {
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $.get("https://example.com/index.html", function (data) {
   const loadpage = async function() {
    var nodes = [...data.childNodes].slice(-3);
    var cont = document.getElementById("container");
    var msg = nodes;

   });
    
        if(cont.innerHTML='') {
         cont.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', msg);
    }   else {
        cont.innerHTML=msg;
     }          
    };
   
   loadpage();
   });
  });
}

load();
```

html looks like this:

```
<main>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
</main>
```

the expected output should be:

```
 <div class="msg">something</div>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
 <div class="msg">something</div>
```

since I want only the last 3 nodes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use async await here and you are doing it wrong

Please read [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function)

Your load is also wrong and too complex. You should not add a window event handler in a function and the test to insert after if cont is empty is not useful. Your test is also not a comparison (== '' or === '') but an assignment (= '').

Add the data to a partial element and slice the result

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const cont = document.getElementById("container");
  $.get("https://example.com/index.html", function(data) {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = data; // assuming HTML string?
    [...div.querySelectorAll('.msg')]
    .slice(-3)
    .forEach(div => cont.innerHTML += div.outerHTML);
  });
});
```

Comment: It didnt work on my end. Please look at my modified code above.

Comment: help please????

Comment: Can I sleep?

See update

Comment: you can if you believe you can

Comment: you have to move the `});` to AFTER where you use. It is async but you do not await

Comment: but it will load the whole document the way it is now if I only change `var msg = nodes;` to `var msg = data;` without waiting.

Comment: okay got it but now Im getting this output: `[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement]`

Comment: I did but I get this: `[{},{},{}]`

Comment: I think I got it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61049576/javascript-regex-how-to-split-html-string-into-array-of-html-elements-and-text

Comment: I made a change. I could do better with a working example